# Removing one category from wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

Well firstly I am horrible with php. This is my  code

```
$myposts = get_posts('showposts=9');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
```

I wanted category "1" to not display so I tried:

```
$myposts = get_posts('cat=-1, showposts=9');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
```

This made all posts stop showing. So I tried selecting only the categories I wanted:

```
$myposts = get_posts('cat=40,41,42,43,etc, showposts=9');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
```

Only 1 post from each category would show up, instead of all of them.

I have the php written on this specific page template, as I would like to use the category elsewhere just not show up on this page. I've tried a few other things but I don't really understand the structure of php and plunking it into random spots hasn't yielded any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.  You can use `get_posts()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or you can use `WP_Query()` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

I'm not sure what your `showposts=9` argument does in your code when you call `get_posts()`?

To get all posts except for those in one category (with ID=1) using get_posts:

```
$myposts = get_posts(array('cat'=>'-1', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
```

The `'cat'=>'-1'` means exclude posts where the category ID is 1 and `'posts_per_page'=>-1` means do not limit the number of posts returned.

Comment: This did the trick thank you! As to the guy below I tried yours first and got a double arrow syntax arrow. I googled it up and it's missing the array as in this example.